# dropwdown div cut off inside its parent container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this html code

```
<div class="cos_data_table_header_right">
    <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

and this css for .cosdata_table_header

```
.cosdata_table_header{
    padding: 10px;
    background: #cacaca;
    display: block;
}
```

The problem is that, the default style of .cosdata_table_header is not wrapping its children yet the dropdown thing is working perfectly but if I set it to overflow: auto, the .cosdata_table_header wraps its children yet if I click the dropdown button, its content has been cut off and a awful scrollbar is shown inside the .cosdata_table_header and if I set the style of .cosdata_table_header to overflow: hidden, the dropdown thing content is not shown (refer below).

[image]

any help, suggestions, recommendations, ideas and clues to make this work?

PS: im using [bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) for the dropdown stuff.

Comment: Have you tried upping the z-index?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring that the html class doesn't match your selector (probably a typo right?) I would say don't make the container display block and make the overflow visible. That way your buttons will be able to live beside other content and the drop down overlap other content without expanding the entire container. I haven't tested but if it was me this is the first thing I would try.

a JSFiddle or a link to the dev site or something would make it easier to see what's going on and to work on an answer

Answer (score -1):

Can you reproduce the problem in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?  I would suggest try to debug your layout in chrome developer tools or Firebug also.